# VBA Fastest way to search a 40mb xml file or convert a binary array of that file to string for searching

Tags: ms-access, vba

Howdy,
I have VBA running behind MS Access.  I need to repeatedly search and retrieve data from a 40mb File.  Its too big to load into a string variable.  I've loaded it into binary array (rather zippily I might add), but I'm at a loss for how to leverage that format.....I can't seem to grasp looping thru the array a byte at a time in search of a string......
  So I dumped that idea...(but I'm willing to learn how to leverage that strategy)..I'm on to FilesystemObject based searching; here's what I have so far:

I get the beggining(x) and end(y) of the node & then put it into the FLat variable.

```
 Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile(DLookup("gsgtver", "Eramdat", "EramID = 1"), ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
 x = InStr(1, ts.ReadAll, ">" & sFirst & "<")

 ts.Close

 Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile(DLookup("gsgtver", "Eramdat", "EramID = 1"), ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
 y = InStr(x, ts.ReadAll, "</FixRecord")

 ts.Close

 Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile(DLookup("gsgtver", "Eramdat", "EramID = 1"), ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
 FLat = Mid(ts.ReadAll, x, y - x)

 ts.Close
```

If I didn't have to do this 10 to 120 times I'd chalk it up to "acceptable wait state", but as you can guess, this ain't acceptable.   Any suggestions on how to do this more slickilly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you're looking for slickiness, so I advise loading your XML file into an XML document object. Why treat the XML information as a string "soup", when it's actually neatly organised in an easily searchable hierarchy?

```
Dim xmlDoc As Object
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.async = False ' Don't ask.
xmlDoc.Load "C:\myfile.xml" 
'Voilà, your XML is loaded and parsed, ready to be searched.
```

See documentation form XML DOMDocuments [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Then you can have random access to the data in the XML document using the XPath notation (tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)), e.g.

```
Set someElement = _
    xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//MyElementName[@MyAttributeName = 'blabla']")
theStringINeed = someElement.Text
```

where the stuff in quotes is an XPath. I'm sure you can retrieve the thing you're looking for using a single XPath statement. The XML object will do the searching for you if you tell it what you're looking for. That's what it's there for.

This is really the correct way of accessing XML-formatted information. Anything else and you're really just making your own life miserable in comparison.

Comment: Looks nifty....I'm in agreement about taking advantage of the XML-ness and yes, my life is miserable in the current wait state ;)

Comment: So...I can't find a good library reference to Dim myself a nice IXMLDOMNode so I can use "someElement". I'm getting an "Object Varialbe not set" error when I try to peak in someElement.text. Its possible that I'm barkin up the wrong node notation; here's what I got: Set someElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/FixRecord/FixID[1]")

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft XML, v6.0` It's already there on my system (Vista/Office 2007).

Comment: I selected that in my reference library....its checked.   I get an IXMLDOMNode choice when I dim my someElement var, I even get the "text" method after my dot (and lots of others) but the error keeps poppin up..... I bet I have the stuff in quotes hosed up a bit...I'll take another peak at the XPath syntax.

Comment: :-(  no joy.   I'm pretty sure I have the SelectSingleNode("/FixRecord/FixID[1]/Latitude") correct...I'm flumuxed.

Comment: These things are a bit tricky to begin with. You have to get the XPath just right. Why don't you ask a new question, showing us part of the input .xml file, so folks can help out. Too much for a comment. Is your xmlDoc created properly? Let us know debug details.

Comment: If you use `CreateObject(something)` then you don't need to select that something in your reference library. This works fine but may bear a small cost -- read VBA help on `CreateObject` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following approach:

1. Loop through each element in 40mb xml file
2. Assign element to string variable
3. Add string variable to a `Collection` object

You end up with a collection of strings that represent your XML.  Then when you need to search it you just do a `For Each` through your string collection and do your comparisons one element at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The next fella has a pretty nifty lookin answer that I think I'll have a go with.....but I'm currious about what a "node" is....

Comment: I agree with your sentiments, though.  If you can use an XML library to accomplish your goal that will almost certainly be your best bet.